# What is the best way to match text with math expressions inside?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, mathml

My problem is to match text with math expressions inside.
I saw this topic - [What is the best way to index documents which contain mathematical expression in elastic search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960265/what-is-the-best-way-to-index-documents-which-contain-mathematical-expression-in)

But in my context I can't just create an additional field with math expression. I have to match text like math tasks for students and these tasks could have multiple math expressions.
I think the MathML is most preferred format here because I can split MathML tags into words and match them as a usual words.

I'm interested to get most close match results to math expressions. What is the most proper way to reach this kind of matching?

Examples:

1. Solve the equation (2x + 7) ^ 2 = (2x - 1) ^ 2 .
2. Find all values of the parameter **a**, for each of which the equation: | x - a ^ 2 + a + 2 | + | x - a ^ 2 + 3a - 1 | = 2a - 3 has roots, but none of them belongs to the interval (4; 19)

   P.S. graphical representation of equation: [image: equation pict]

Comment: Can you share a sample document?

Comment: @Val added examples to question

Comment: I think it would be still a good idea to extract equations or math expressions into their own fields, keeping them in the description. Maybe even have three kinds of fields: description field containing human-readable text, you wouldn't index it. And then two separate fields: description without equations and equations where each of them would be analyzed differently. Then you could use `multi_match` to query both of them. Trying to index a single field with very, very, very different rules will be unpractical.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Yes, I thought about it too, MathML expressions can be easily extracted from text, because they're have XML markup. And if I understand you correct it also is possible to rank matches by math expressions match score.

Comment: There's nothing out of the box that would work for you, so you'd need to build a custom analyzer or parser for that. But it should be possible. The main idea is to separate searchable and user-facing fields due to completely different search semantics. :)